# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements in Distribution profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have seen a number of solutions for this on stack overflow but none of them is working. I have tried all of these :
1. Restarting XCode
2. Matching capabilities on AppId and Project capibilities
3. Removing derived data from XCode preferences

Still I receive this issue.
I am using distribution profile.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check once in your keychain Access your Distribution certificate is valid or not.